# Pb with my computations when I use screen

Tags: server, python, screen

I have some heavy computations to run. So, instead of running them in my computer I use the university's server by running the following command:

```
screen
python3.6 main.py > output.txt
```

The output.txt file is used to save the output of the console so that I can see where it goes wrong. It used to work miraculously, however, lately (without changing the script at all)  I have started to notice that the computations are not completed, with no error whatsoever signaled in the output.txt file, and I just don't know why.

Any ideas of workarounds or what I should check for it to work?

PS: I am very much still a fresh newbie in the Ubuntu world, but I love to learn new stuff and hacks, so please go easy on me :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without knowing anything about your system, the school’s server, or the code, nobody here will be able to say much beyond “reach out to the admins at the university”. There are simply too many unknowns …

Comment: @matigo will do. Thank you!

Comment: @matigo I have one question though: since I have to 'cd' to a given directory to run computations, does running 'killall screen' kill all the screens running in that particular directory, or all screens running in the server?

Comment: This should really be written as a separate question, as it's completely different from the one above. That said, it kills the screen session(s) owned by your user account. If you want to kill all screens on the server, then you'll need admin privileges.

Comment: @matigo Because I have used this command several times, and now that I am thinking about it, maybe when I used in other directories to stop the computations there, I ended up killing all the screens running in my user account. Thank you for your response :)